# How to receive json array and iterate it in service file in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working in an Angular4 application,In this I need to receive and iterate the json objects and pass it to another component.Here I have tried something please help me to solve this.

json response format

[image]

service file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class CartdataService {

  public i_product_Path = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
  i_cast_Product_Path = this.i_product_Path.asObservable();

  i_COUNTER :number;
  big_Image_Path:string[][];
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 get_Product_Path(pName: string) {
    this.current_product = pName.trim();
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:57036/api/data/GetImage/?imageName=${this.current_product}`)
    .subscribe((data) => {

        this.i_COUNTER = data[0].Count;
 if(this.i_COUNTER >0) {
          let i:number;
            for( i=0;i<=this.i_COUNTER;i++){
              this.big_Image_Path =data[0]['big_Images'];
            }
        }
 this.i_product_Path.next(this.big_Image_Path);
 });
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please provide text of your json reponse ??

Comment: @PranayRana,

[[{"big_Images":"assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Show1.png"},{"big_Images":"assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Show2.png"},{"big_Images":"assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Show3.png"}],[{"small_Images":"assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Product_Details_Page_Thumbnails/bal1.png"},{"small_Images":"assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Product_Details_Page_Thumbnails/bal2.png"},{"small_Images":"assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Product_Details_Page_Thumbnails/bal3.png"}],[{"selected_Product_Image":"assets/Images/Modal_Screen/added.png"}]]

Comment: you received this as response , nothing else right ?, because right now its showing invalid json

Comment: check the text here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: @PranayRana did you check it ?

Comment: yes , trying to convert you json string in object

Comment: @PranayRana Okay thanks

Comment: Added my answer you can try that , I took constant string as input and tried it you will get same string as reponse

Comment: thanks for acceptance , I hope things worked for you , I tried my best to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your input string this is working code,

```
  parseJsonToObj() {
    const json = '[[{ "big_Images": "assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Show1.png" }, { "big_Images": "assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Show2.png" }, { "big_Images": "assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Show3.png" }], [{ "small_Images": "assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Product_Details_Page_Thumbnails/bal1.png" }, { "small_Images": "assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Product_Details_Page_Thumbnails/bal2.png" }, { "small_Images": "assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Product_Details_Page_Thumbnails/bal3.png" }], [{ "selected_Product_Image": "assets/Images/Modal_Screen/added.png" }]]'
    const images: Images = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(images);
  }
```

To handle json created interfaces like below which can get your data easily,

```
export interface Images {
  big_Images: BImage[];
  small_Images: Simage[];
  selected_Product_Images: SelectedImage[]
}

export interface BImage {
  big_Images: string;
}

export interface Simage {
  small_Images: string;
}

export interface SelectedImage {
  selected_Product_Image: string;
}
```

Basically I am converting json response to typescript object.

---

with given structure this should work for you

```
  this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      (response: Images ) => {    
          console.log(response); 
      },
      error => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      },
      () => { }
    );
```

[image]

Comment: this.CartdataService.i_cast_Product_Path.subscribe( (response : Images ) =>
    { this.images.big_Images = response.big_Images; });

by using this code I got undefined as output ,I need to extract all individual path from model and assign it to the local variable for display it

Comment: @Pranay Rana , Looking for your reply

Comment: My doubt is all about I am just calling the api url inside the service file but I am not passing anything from  get_Product_Path this method to my-cart.compont.ts then how  can I get the response in my-cart.component.ts

Comment: <span >hi--{{images}}</span>

I got [object object] as the output 

I want to get all the image paths from model to bind specific images

Comment: @PranayRana I have implemented everything in my system.

Comment: @PranayRana ,https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkmfsu?file=app%2Fcartdata.service.ts

Comment: @Nikson - just put this line in you component html `<span *ngFor="let image of images.big_Images">
  {{image}}
</span>`

Comment: @Nikson - check update here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkmfsu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @PranayRana ,there is no change after applying this code.
Before that got [object object] but now nothing is displayed

Comment: Will I get any reply ?

Comment: @PranayRana ,Looking for your response ,When I put debgger; after 

this.image = response;  I got " " as response

Comment: @Nikson - if you are getting "" as response , then check your service is returning data or not

Comment: If I call the same URL in browser it returns the data as in the above image.But inside my application I can't see the output

Comment: @PranayRana ,In service file I tried to display the API res in console It displayed all the expected data ,But when I am retrieve the data from model in component it returns " "

Comment: @PranayRana, is there any other way to consume data from model in components .?

Comment: @Nikson - can you change code like this    `ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.i_cast_Product_Path.subscribe( (response : any ) =>
    { 
      console.log(response);
      this.images = response.json(); });
  }` in component

Comment: @Nikson - in service code `   get_Product_Path(pName: string) : Observable<any> {
    this.current_product = pName.trim();
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:abc/api/data/GetImage/?imageName=${this.current_product}`);
  }`

Comment: @Nikson - find update here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkmfsu?file=app%2Fcartdata.service.ts

Comment: @PranayRana it returns response.json is not a function

Comment: @PranayRana, Please check all the component and model ,service 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkmfsu?file=app%2Fcartdata.service.ts

Comment: @PranayRana ,What should I do next

Comment: @Nikson - just try this `   ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.i_cast_Product_Path.subscribe( (response : any ) =>
    { 
      console.log(response);
    });` and let me know what you are getting in console

Comment: @PranayRana ,Okay

Comment: @PranayRana,I have attached the image of the console output please check it

Comment: @Nikson - can you check what all property of it and find which property contains your reponse value i.e. json value

Comment: @PranayRana The response values are not present in it

Comment: @Nikson - you will not get as you did call method get response , check my update here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkmfsu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts..i made call to service method to get data , and please go though some basic course of how to get data from server in agnular 2